# grunt no longer compiling and minifying my stuff

Tags: gruntjs

I ran `npm install && bower install` with no hiccup. Now I am trying to compile my assets but I am getting the following error:

```
--- (master) $ grunt
Usage: grunt INPUT_FILE [options]

grunt: error: Input file not provided.
```

Here is my `package.json` that I used to install grunt...

```
{
  "name": "foundation-libsass-template",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-debian-package": "^0.1.9",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "~0.7.0"
  }
}
```

I am running the `grunt` command from the same directory as my `Gruntfile.js`. Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
      options: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'css/babynet.css': 'scss/babynet.scss',
          'css/epals2.css': 'scss/epals2.scss',
        }        
      }
    },

    watch: {
      grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },

      sass: {
        files: 'scss/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build','watch']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just speculation. The `grunt: error: Input file not provided.` error makes me wonder if an older grunt is being run and is looking for the older `grunt.js` file rather than `Gruntfile.js`.

Check the output of `grunt --version`, if it is a pre 0.4 release then the problem may be what I outlined above. From http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4:

> The "Gruntfile" has changed from grunt.js to Gruntfile.js.

Comment: `grunt: error: no such option: --version` and `which grunt >>
/Users/nathann/code/ipals/env/bin/grunt` and `ls -l >> Gruntfile.js`

Comment: Hmm... here is how I installed grunt: `npm install -g grunt-cli`. For `which grunt` I simply get: `/usr/local/bin/grunt`. My output for `grunt --version`: `grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5`

Comment: Wow. I figured it out. So, i'm using this in the context of a django project with a `virtualenv` if i deactivate my env it works and if i activate it does not work. so i ran `pip uninstall grunt` and deactivated and reactivated and then grunt worked. cool.

Comment: So the `virtualenv` had an older grunt version installed?